# Is there a way to run some tests sequentially with Jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, create-react-app

[Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/) runs your test suite in parallel by default, but there is a flag (`--runInBand`) that allows you to run the whole suite sequentially (as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32751695/how-to-run-jest-tests-sequentially))

I have some tests that cannot run in parallel, but running the whole suite sequentially takes a lot longer in total, so my question is if there is way to only run *some* tests that way (such as setting a flag for those tests or something similar).

Comment: _"I have some tests that cannot run in parallel"_ - This usually hints tests aren't independent, a bigger problem... Or what you're doing isn't and shouldn't be a unit test.

Comment: yeah, I am launching an external service for pact.js which is not that trivial to change. An acceptable compromise for me would be if I can isolate those tests and have them run sequentially without losing the speed for the whole suite

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I too needed the same functionality. I have a large set of Jest integration test suites I want to run. However, some can't be run in parallel due to the need of setup and teardown of a shared resource. So, here is the solution I came up with.

I updated my `package.json` scripts from:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "npm run test:unit && npm run test:integration",
    "test:integration": "jest --config=__tests__/integration/jest.config.js",
    "test:unit": "jest --config=__tests__/unit/jest.config.js"
  },
  ...
}
```

to

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "npm run test:unit && npm run test:integration",
    "test:integration": "npm run test:integration:sequential && npm run test:integration:parallel",
    "test:integration:parallel": "jest --config=__tests__/integration/jest.config.js",
    "test:integration:sequential": "jest --config=__tests__/integration/jest.config.js --runInBand",
    "test:unit": "jest --config=__tests__/unit/jest.config.js"
  },
  ...
}
```

Then I updated `__tests__/integration/jest.config.js` from

```
module.exports = {
  // Note: rootDir is relative to the directory containing this file.
  rootDir: './src',
  setupFiles: [
    '../setup.js',
  ],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    ...
  ],
};
```

to

```
const Path = require('path');

const { defaults } = require('jest-config');
const klawSync = require('klaw-sync')
const mm = require('micromatch');

// Note: rootDir is relative to the directory containing this file.
const rootDir = './src';
const { testMatch } = defaults;

// TODO: Add the paths to the test suites that need to be run
// sequentially to this array.
const sequentialTestPathMatchPatterns = [
  '<rootDir>/TestSuite1ToRunSequentially.spec.js',
  '<rootDir>/TestSuite2ToRunSequentially.spec.js',
  ...
];

const parallelTestPathIgnorePatterns = [
  ...
];

let testPathIgnorePatterns = [
  ...parallelTestPathIgnorePatterns,
  ...sequentialTestPathMatchPatterns,
];

const sequential = process.argv.includes('--runInBand');
if (sequential) {
  const absRootDir = Path.resolve(__dirname, rootDir);
  let filenames = klawSync(absRootDir, { nodir: true })
    .map(file => file.path)
    .map(file => file.replace(absRootDir, ''))
    .map(file => file.replace(/\\/g, '/'))
    .map(file => '<rootDir>' + file);
  filenames = mm(filenames, testMatch);
  testPathIgnorePatterns = mm.not(filenames, sequentialTestPathMatchPatterns);
}

module.exports = {
  rootDir,
  setupFiles: [
    '../setup.js',
  ],
  testMatch,
  testPathIgnorePatterns,
};
```

The updated `jest.config.js` depends on `jest-config`, `klaw-sync`, and `micromatch`.

```
npm install --save-dev jest-config klaw-sync micromatch
```

Now, you can run `npm run test:integration:sequential` if you only want to run the tests that need to be run sequentially.

Or run `npm run test:integration:parallel` for the parallel tests.

Or run `npm run test:integration` to first run the sequential tests. Then when that is finished, the parallel tests will run.

Or run `npm run test` to run both the unit and integration tests.

Note: The directory structure I am using with my unit and integration tests is as follows:

```
__tests__
  integration
    src
      *.spec.js
      *.test.js
    jest.config.js
  unit
    src
      *.spec.js
      *.test.js
    jest.config.js
```

Comment: So much hassle for just quite a simple thing, Jest really lacks very important feature to mark describe block to be run sequential.

Comment: In the end it will run both suite sequentially if the first don't fail. Is this wanted?

Comment: in jest's defense - running tests with a worker pool is the smart thing. in our defense - clearing out a database before/after each test is also a smart thing to do and the two are completely at odds. thanks for the tip about the `--runInBand` flag! definitely saved me. all my tests started failing after I started doing proper cleanup before each test.

Answer (score 5):

Extended from [Joachim Lous](https://stackoverflow.com/users/628371/joachim-lous)'s answer, you can divide test files into projects and specify a different runner for each project.

In `jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  projects: [
    {
      displayName: "default-tests",
      testEnvironment: "node",
    },
    {
      displayName: "serial-tests",
      testEnvironment: "node",
      runner: "jest-serial-runner",
      testMatch: ["**/?(*.)+(serial-test).[jt]s?(x)"],
    },
  ],
}
```

Then, rename any tests that need to be run sequentially to `*.serial-test.js` (as opposed to `*.test.js`).

Answer (score 4):

Use the serial test runner:

```
npm install jest-serial-runner --save-dev
```

Set up jest to use it, e.g. in jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
   ...,
   runner: 'jest-serial-runner'
};
```

You can use the project feature to apply it only to a subset of tests. See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#projects-arraystring--projectconfig

Comment: To whoever voted this down: it would be more helpful to everyone if you commented what you thought was wrong or could be improved.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bit of a lift, but I think it's worth posting my final config. I had this same problem and I extended [Joachim Lous'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/628371/joachim-lous) and [Fishball's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2569501/fishball) answers to get to a satisfactory result. Here's my final setup:

An abbreviated directory listing of my project:

```
├── src
│   ├── index.ts
│   ├── Io.ts
│   ├── Modules
│   │   └── index.ts
│   └── .....
└── tests
    ├── EndToEnd
    │   ├── Fixtures.ts
    │   ├── Mq.spec.ts
    │   ├── LegalEntities.spec.ts
    │   └── Utils.ts
    └── UnitTests
        ├── LegalEntities.spec.ts
        ├── Assets.spec.ts
        └── Utils.ts
```

My (abbreviated) `package.json` file with my jest configs in it:

```json
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "scripts/build",
    "check": "tsc --noEmit",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "....": "....",
  "jest": {
    "projects": [
      {
        "displayName": "unit-tests",
        "testEnvironment": "node",
        "verbose": true,
        "testMatch": [
          "<rootDir>/tests/**/*.spec.ts",
          "!**/EndToEnd/**/*.spec.ts"
        ],
        "transform": {
          "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
        }
      },
      {
        "displayName": "e2e-tests",
        "testEnvironment": "node",
        "verbose": true,
        "maxWorkers": 1,
        "testMatch": [
          "<rootDir>/tests/EndToEnd/**/*.spec.ts"   
        ],
        "transform": {
          "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Things to note:

- When using the `projects` key in jest, I had to move *all* config into the individual project blocks. Using project config was mutually-exclusive with using global config.
- **I did not use the `runner` directive as mentioned in other answers. Instead I used the `maxWorkers` option to limit execution to 1 worker (i.e., inherently serial).** This meant I didn't have to use more dependencies.
- For some reason the negation syntax was finicky with my unit tests. I wanted to specify unit tests as all tests that were NOT in the `EndToEnd` directory, and it took me a few tried to get jest to do this correctly.

Thanks to everyone else for the viable starting point. Hope this helps others!

Comment: Interestingly, this setup shouldn't work (and didn't for me). See this issue: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/10936
maxWorkers is ignored on the project level.