# running selenium tests on parallel using jest

Tags: selenium, jestjs

I have used the example from : https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#defining-multiple-flows

and trying to run the test parallelly so that each browser will be concurrently executed. Here is the script:

```
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');

var browsers = [
    { browserName: 'chrome' },
    { browserName: 'firefox'},
];

browsers.map(browser => {
    describe('Google Search', function() {
        let driver;

        beforeEach(async function() {
            driver = await new Builder().forBrowser(browser.browserName).build();
        }, 10 * 1000);

        afterEach(async function() {
            await driver.quit();
        });

        it('example', async function() {
            await driver.get('https://www.google.com/ncr');
            await driver.manage().setTimeouts({ implicit: 5000 })
            await driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver', Key.RETURN);
            await driver.wait(until.titleIs('webdriver - Google Search'), 1000);
        }, 10 * 1000);
    });
});
```

My knowledge in jest/jscript is limited. Apologies if there is anything fundamentally wrong.

I have tried both running locally and running against zalenium. In both cases, tests are running sequentially.

Thank you for the Help in making the script run parallelly.

Comment: afaik jest may run each file in own thred, not each declaration inside single file. and what's a point? do you want to perform load testing?

Comment: Yes, I want the tests to run concurrently so that it takes much less time.

Comment: I mean you are ruining exactly same test for several times here. if you do functional testing you may split test into several files and they should run well in parallel.

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47291189/is-there-a-way-to-run-some-tests-sequentially-with-jest?rq=1