# How to setup Jest with Selenium to run some tests in parallel and some tests in sequentially?

Tags: javascript, selenium, automated-tests, jestjs

I use Selenium webdriver js for automation testing, also I use **Jest** to run  some test in parralell and my tests have this structure:

```
tests
 ┣ folder1
 ┃ ┣ suite1
 ┃ ┣ suite2
 ┃ ┣ suite3
 ┃ ┗ suite4
 ┣ folder2
 ┃ ┣ suite1
 ┃ ┣ suite2
 ┃ ┣ suite3
 ┃ ┗ suite4
 ┣ folder3
 ┃ ┣ suite1
 ┃ ┣ suite2
 ┃ ┗ suite3
```

I want to run in parallel [folder1, folder2, folder3], but all tests from this each should run in sequentially, if I use **--runInBand** it will run all suites in sequentially, does'n matter if it is from another folder

For example at the same time I want to start

**suite1** from **test1** + **suite1** from **test2** + **suite1** from **test3**

If some **suite** will finished, it will start next **suite** from the same folder.

Why? Because if I will run it without **--runInBand**, it will open a chrome window for each test, and imagine how much **RAM** it will consume

Comment: Best practice is to not have tests dependent on each other. Given that, you should just run all tests in parallel and let the runner run them in whatever order is needed to execute efficiently. Why do you need to run them in this specific way?

Comment: there is no one dependent test, I want to run it in this way because it will be faster, in my case 1 suite run in 1-2 min

Comment: Put all tests into a pool and let the runner run them, that's likely the fastest way. Depending on the runner you use, some have extra intelligence and uses run time, etc. to better balance the runs.

Comment: Can you give an example ?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47291189/is-there-a-way-to-run-some-tests-sequentially-with-jest?rq=1