# How to run a single test suite in Jest?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

I have many test suites. I wanna to run a singe one and skip all the others, and I would like to do this on the code level.

I know I can do this using .only() and .skip() in a test file, but that supports only the tests / describes defined in that file.

Is there a way to do this globally? Like is there something like .only() which - when called on the top level describe - runs only that test suite and all others are skipped?
Or: when called on a single test ( it().only() ), then only that test runs and nothing else?

I see nothing like this in the API, but maybe Jest can be configured to work this way?

Is this possible with Jest or is this something I can only do via CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly: You want to run just one test suite/file.

You can do this from the command line with `jest path/to/filename.test.js`.

Within a file, you can use `test.only(name, fn, timeout)` to only run that test. This won't stop Jest from moving on to the next testing file though.

[Full Jest CLI docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli)

As far as I am aware, you cannot do this from within the test file itself.
The closest I can think of would be to set the `testmatch' in Jest's config to a pattern that only matches the file(s) you want run.

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "jest": {
    "testmatch": "**/my.test.js"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know all that. The question is how can I run only a single test or test suite without the CLI? You can do this with Mocha / Chai / Sinon for example, I'm just wondering if this is also possible with Jest

Comment: As far as I am aware, you can't do this in Jest in the .test.js file itself.
Closest I can think of would be using the `testmatch` key in jest's config file.
Updating answer....

Answer (score 0):

I think if you adapt this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59487370/14553660 it should give you what you need.

For example:

`testsuite.test.js`

```
import { signuptests } from './signup.test.js'
import { logintests } from './login.test.js'
import { logouttests } from './logout.test.js'

describe('Signup', signuptests)
describe.only('Login', logintests)
describe('Logout', logouttests)
```

`signup.test.js`

```
export const signuptests = () => {
     it('Should have login elements', () => {});
     it('Should Signup', () => {}});
}
```

`login.test.js`

```
export const logintests = () => {
    it.only('Should Login', () => {}});
    it('etc',()=>{});
}
```

`logout.test.js`

```
export const logouttests = () => {
    it('Should Logout', () => {}});
    it('etc',()=>{});
}
```

You will be able to use `.only` at the top level - in the testsuite file - to determine which test files are run, and you can also use `.only` within each individual test file (e.g. within login.test.js) to only run one particular test from that file.

I don't know that there is a limit to nesting describe blocks, so I imagine you could even make a 'master-testsuite' that imports different testsuites (which in turn import different test files...etc)